# APNS Push notification Background non working anymore

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios13, silentpush

Sorry to repost this question as it was asked a few times, but no answer was ok for me.
My app don't wake up anymore on background notification.
So I updated my php script and added HEADERs field as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns#2947607) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app) 
But no luck.

Here my sample code :

```
<?php

$device_token = 'd98e1d488acac56305a9f83b...b616bc5b5b3bf238dc'; 
//$device_token = '27b296397f81f48590a....fe2742e0b2a051ae2cefffded85d7';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$pem_secret = '';
$pem_file = 'pushcert.pem';
$url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";


//$body = '{"aps":{"alert":"balbla","badge":0,"sound":"default"}}';
$body = '{"aps":{"content-available":1},"acme1":"bar"}';
$header = ['apns-topic'=>'com.blabla.bla',
    'apns-push-type'=>'background',
    'apns-priority'=>'5'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $pem_secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$information = curl_getinfo($ch);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//On successful response you should get true in the response and a status code of 200
//A list of responses and status codes is available at 
//https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1
//var_dump($header);
//var_dump($information);
var_dump($response);
var_dump($httpcode);
```

?>

I never enter the iOS methode to catch this notification :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:userInfo forKey:@"testtesttest"];
// Method called when user click on notification and application is in background
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
NSLog(@"did received remote notification");  }
```

Also in my device console, it seems that the device is canceling my notifications or something a don't get.
[image]

Also not that standard notifications (not in Background) works fine.
testing iOS 13.3.1

Thanks a lot for any help you could get me.

Background mode enabled :

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
    <string>processing</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

[image]

App Settings also configured :
[image]

Comment: Did you enable UIBackgroundModes to "remote-notification" in info.plist? Also, pls enable Background App Refresh options in Settings app of the device.

Comment: Hi Anand, Thanks for your help, I checked again and Yes background mode is enabled in .plist and App System Settings. (I updated my post)

Comment: Did you check this: Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh?

Comment: @Anand My app don't appears in that list indeed ? why then ? how to make it listed in there ?

Comment: Please check the capabilities in your project

Comment: as you can see capabilities a all checked in my project. I launch a another phone, and the app appears in the list on that one. Still I don't get any background notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it Work with that sample code:

```
<?php

// open connection
if (!defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0')) {
    define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 3);
}
$device_token = 'd56e9ef8b5ea558f07584cf8...498824ece60a36229446a2003116'; //David

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$pem_secret = '';
$pem_file = 'pushcert.pem';
$url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com/3/device/$device_token";
$app_bundle_id = "com.blabla.blabla";

//$body = '{"aps":{"alert":"balbla","badge":0,"sound":"default"}}';
$body = '{  
            "aps":{"content-available":1},
            "type":"LOCATION",
            "idRequest":"538EAC3E765A4BDC89B554C40F5B14EF"
        }';

$headers = array(
    "apns-topic: {$app_bundle_id}",
    "User-Agent: My Sender",
    "apns-push-type:background",
    "apns-priority:5"
);

 var_dump($body);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT,443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pem_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$information = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

//On successful response you should get true in the response and a status code of 200
//A list of responses and status codes is available at 
//https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW1
//var_dump($header);
var_dump($information);
var_dump($response);
var_dump($httpcode);
```

?>

Well at least it seems that the application is waking up (seen in the device log)

- So this morning I launch the code from yesterday (with no modifications at all) and it worked for a few times, like 4 or 5 times.
- Now it doesn't work anymore. Same as yesterday (iOS system seems to catch the payload, but application is not waked up)

-> conclusion, this a system limitation, and this is so confusing when you need to perfom tests. I'm gonna put this in production with no assurance it will work properly...